# Change One Word's Weight in a H1 CSS

Tags: html, css, text, positioning

I've been trying to find out how to do the following for quite some time now. Obviously, I can solve this problem by having different h1s and position them, but I want to know if I can solve this problem without dividing these two into different h1s.

So here we go.

HTML:

```
<h1 id = "introText1">Hi, my name is Liam Shalon.</h1>
```

CSS:

```
#introText1 {
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    left: 0;
    line-height: 200px;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: -110px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

I need:

- "Hi, my name is" to be with weight 300
- "Liam Shalon" to be with weight 400

How can I do that WITHOUT having to split it up into two h1s? Is there a way?

Thanks
Liam

Comment: could you use `<span>Liam Shalon</span>`?

Comment: I did not realize that you could wrap text within the h1 in "a"s or "span"s. That is the way to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<h1 id="introText1">Hi, my name is <span>Liam Shalon.</span></h1>
```

**CSS**

```
#introText1 {
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    left: 0;
    line-height: 200px;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: -110px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
}

span {
    font-weight: 900;
}
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/9kCeT/2/

Please note that I intentionally increased the font-weight to emphasize the `<span>` tag. A `font-weight` difference of 100 wasn't very noticeable on the fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap one of the portions in a `<span>`, with a class to override the weight.  Like:

**HTML**:

```
<h1 id = "introText1">Hi, my name is <span class="heavy">Liam Shalon.</span></h1>
```

**CSS**:

```
.heavy {
 font-weight: 400;
}
```

And leave the h1 with a normal weight of 300.

Comment: i don't want to kill your thunder, but `weight` is not a valid CSS tag (at least JSFiddle doesn't like it) http://jsfiddle.net/9kCeT/1/

Comment: Sorry, forgot the 'font-'  :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use span tags within the H1. Use it the same way you're using CSS with the id, but do something like:

```
<h1 id = "introText1"><span id="textOne">Hi, my name is</span><span id="textTwo">Liam Shalon.</span></h1>
```